# If any orthogonal matrix does pure rotation, what's the rotation angle of this matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, geometry, rotations, orthogonal-matrices

I'm perplexed by this orthogonal matrix, it doesn't seem to be doing consistent rotation action:

$$
1/\sqrt{2}
\begin{bmatrix}
   1 & 1 \\
   1 & -1
\end{bmatrix}
$$

It doesn't follow the standard 2d rotation matrix definition, in the sense that there's no angle that gives rise to this matrix. So, what's going on?

Comment: for some vectors, it seem to rotate by 45 degrees, for others -45 degrees, it is not consistent.

Comment: check the determinant -- that is not an orthogonal matrix.  In fact for a 'pure rotation' you'd need orthogonal with determinant =1 (SO2)

Comment: Only the orthogonal $2\times 2$ matrices with determinant $1$ correspond, geometrically, to rotations of $\Bbb R^2$. The ones with determinant $-1$ correspond to reflections.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Some have pointed out that this is not an orthogonal matrix. But if you multiply it by $1/\sqrt 2,$ then it is, and you're back to square one.

Some orthogonal matrices have determinant $+1$ and others $-1.$ The ones with determinant $1$ represent rotations; the others reflections.

Comment: _"the others reflections"_ — not quite: the others generally may be a composition of a reflection and a rotation.

Comment: @Ruslan : Some mathematicians call those reflections.

Answer (score 3):

Your matrix is *not* an orthogonal matrix and therefore it does not correspond to a rotation.

Comment: give it a norm factor of 1/sqrt(2) and they are orthogonal, and orthonormal

Comment: Yes, it will. But its determinant will be negative, and therefore it still won't correspond to a rotation.

Comment: But it preserves the lengths !! I just jumped to Wiki, the defintion of orthongonal matrix is when A_T * A = I. And it does satisfy that

Comment: As I wrote in the previous comment, yes, it will be orthogonal then. And, yes, it preserves lengths. But it will **not** be a rotation; it will be a reflection on a line.

Answer (score -1):

To be explicit, this matrix is a composition of a rotation by $45°$ and a reflection along the $y$ coordinate:

$$\frac1{\sqrt2}
\begin{pmatrix}
   1 & 1 \\
   1 & -1
\end{pmatrix}=
\begin{pmatrix}
\cos\frac\pi4 & -\sin\frac\pi4 \\
\sin\frac\pi4 & \phantom{+}\cos\frac\pi4
\end{pmatrix}\cdot
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 \\
0 & -1
\end{pmatrix}.$$